# Simplest way to make HTTP request in Spring

Tags: web-services, spring, httpclient, resttemplate

In my Spring web application I need to make an HTTP request to a non-RESTful API, and parse the response body back as a String (it's a single-dimension CSV list).

I've used `RestTemplate` before, but this isn't RESTful and doesn't map nicely on to classes. Whenever I implement something like this 'by hand' (eg using `HttpClient`) I invariably find out later that Spring has a utility class that makes things much simpler.

Is there anything in Spring that will do this job 'out of the box'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the source of RestTemplate you will find that internally it uses

```
java.net.URL
```

and

```
url.openConnection()
```

that is the standard way in Java to make HTTP calls, so you are safe to use that. If there would be a "HTTP client" utility in spring then the RestTemplate would use that too.

Answer (score 3):

I use the Spring Boot with Spring 4.3 Core inside and found a very simple way to make Http request and read responses by using OkHttpClient. Here is the code

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().method("PUT", "some your request body")
            .url(YOUR_URL)
            .build();
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        try
        {
            Response response = httpClient.newBuilder()
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
            .newCall(request)
            .execute();
            if(response.isSuccessful())
            {
                // notification about succesful request
            }
            else
            {
                // notification about failure request
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            // notification about other problems
        }
```

Comment: The imports would be very helpful here.